# Installing DirectX "A Cabinet file cannot be trusted"

Tags: directx

I am trying to install the latest version of DirectX from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/resultsForProduct.aspx?displaylang=en&productID=9C954C37-1ED1-4846-8A7D-85FC422D1388) but I get the following issue. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First run services.msc from run box in start menu. Then in the list check that Cryptographic Services are running. Also, to be safe, set it to automatic.

If the problem isn't solved, go  [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3b170b25-abab-4bc3-ae91-50ceb6d8fa8d&displaylang=en) and download newest version of DirectX from there. Another option is go [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=2DA43D38-DB71-4C1B-BC6A-9B6652CD92A3&displaylang=en) and download websetup. Run this program every two or three months or so and it will download and install newest version of DirectX. Also it only downloads updated files so it transfers less data.

If all fails, it could be that you have problems with Internet connection (bad router, modem etc.), problems with RAM or a virus.

Answer (score 0):

Download Another one here : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=19743
Do not download at the other link it is bad.Or you can try something else.Go to %temp% and delete all files except windows explorer.Bye!